# objective c ios checked more cell with one touch

Tags: ios

I want checked more cell with one click(touch).

In this code I try to do what I said bat ... I have some problem

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *riga;
int esci=0;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[listad objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
riga=[itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"riga"];

for (int i=0; i<[righeS count]; i++) {
    if ([righeS objectAtIndex:i] ==riga) {
                cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        //[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        [righeS removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                     esci=1;
        }
}

if (esci==0) {

    [righeS addObject:riga];
             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;


             //Check if value of qty of the next row is 0
             bool trovato=FALSE;
         for (int g =0 ;g <[listad count];g++){
             NSDictionary *rigaScan=(NSDictionary*)[listad objectAtIndex:g];
            if (trovato==TRUE) {
                 if ([[rigaScan objectForKey:@"qty"] isEqualToString: @"0"]){
                     NSString *rig;
                     rig=[rigaScan objectForKey:@"riga"];
                     [righeS addObject:rig];

                    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                }else{
                   break;
                }    
            }
            if ([rigaScan objectForKey:@"riga"]==riga){
               trovato=TRUE;
            }

           [rigaScan release];
       }

           //Fine controllo


}


}
```

In this event I try when the user touches a cell to see if some value of the next cell is 0.
If the value is 0, I have to check also the next cell and the other value in the for iterate.
When the next value is !=0 I put break.

I believe that the logical code is correct but maybe not the syntax for cocoa.

Comment: Just let me get one thing straight, what you basically want is to have have multiple cells checked?

Comment: yes,i select one and if the other next are some field 0 checked then

Comment: So you select one, and you check if the rest of cells have a certain a field with the value 0, if YES, then select it too?

Comment: @mrhawk yes is it so is pefect!!! the rest of next rows!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this wonderful post from Cocoa With Love - [**Multiple row selection and editing in a UITableView**](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html)

Comment: thank's Srikar for your answer ,infact i download the source code of that link bat this i just done.My problem is another when user check one row or cell if the next rows are for example a value 0 they automatically check too.

Comment: well i knew as much! IT's not an exact solution but you can tweak it to fit your needs. Let me know if any more help is needed..

Comment: i need help yet because i did not receive a solution for my problem.i repeat here what i want.  if i have six row in a tableview if i click the 4 row now for row is checked, i need check also the 5 and 6 row because thei have value for example 0. bat this last check 5 and 6 row the app done automatically the user can't check the row 5 and 6.ok?